# JSF - how to optimize database performance

Tags: sql, jsf, jsf-2, oracle11g

I'm interested how to develop JSF-2.0 web application with maximum database queries performance. Buying powerful hardware is not always the solution.
If I use simple SQL statements instead framework such as Hibernate would this speed up the performance?

Regards
Peter

Comment: This is like saying "If I use simple engine components or a lego-technics kit, will my new car engine be more efficient"?  The solution to database performance is the design of the tables and indexes, and writing queries that understand what the database needs to do to fulfill that query.  In short, you need to learn the skills and techniques of relational database design and programming.  Sorry, there is no universal panacea or shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would. The more the database has to think the slower it gets.

BUT! If you require complex information structures it can increase overall performance to let the Database do the thinking instead of the Java Part.
It really depends on what exactly you want to do and for every query the answer might differ.

Also you should weigh in if your programmer time is more valuable than a faster system so it might be that even though a framework like hibernate is less optimal in performance it is so much faster developed that the 20k € saved gives you a lot more performance on the hardware edge. This also depends on the project though.